# How to verify user input value with the device sim number in phoneGAP?

Tags: javascript, cordova, plugins

I need to verify user input value with the device **SIM number** in phoneGAP eclipse. I am using **Simon Mac Donald Telephone Number Plugin**:

[Telephone Number Plugin](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/300)
and  his blog post as well [blog post](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-get-devices-phone-number-using.html)

when I run the code it always goes on error ...

CODE :

**JAVA**

```
  package com.simonmacdonald.cordova.plugins;
  import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
  import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
  import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

   public class TelephoneNumber extends CordovaPlugin {

   public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) {

    if (action.equals("get")) {

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)this.cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        String result = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();

        if (result != null) {

            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result));

            return true;
        }
    }
    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR));

    return false;
}
}
```

**Telephone.Js**

```
  cordova.define("cordova/plugin/telephonenumber",
  function(require, exports, module) {
var exec = require("cordova/exec");
var TelephoneNumber = function () {};

var TelephoneNumberError = function(code, message) {
    this.code = code || null;
    this.message = message || '';

    //alert("message = " + this.message + this.code);
};



TelephoneNumber.NO_TELEPHONE_NUMBER = 0;

TelephoneNumber.prototype.get = function(success,fail) {
    var errorCallback = typeof fail !== 'function' ? null : function(code) {
        fail({"code": code});


        //alert("TelephoneNumber.prototype.get = ");
    };
    exec(success,errorCallback,"TelephoneNumber", "get",[]);
};

var telephoneNumber = new TelephoneNumber();
module.exports = telephoneNumber;

//alert("telephoneNumber = " +  module.exports);
  });
```

** Device.Ready**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var pushNotification;

        function onDeviceReady() {

            alert("Device Ready");


          var telephoneNumber = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/telephonenumber");
            telephoneNumber.get(function(result) {
                    console.log("result = " + result);
                    alert("result = " + result);
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log("error = " + error.code);
                    alert("error = " + error.code);
                });
}
</script>
```

**How can I resolve this error or should I need to search other  solution to achieve  it ?**

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: It just went to function(error){} :(